# Tips for improving implementation of Wagner-Fischer-algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, optimization, time-complexity

So I'm working on an implementation of a [Wagner-Fischer-Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Fischer_algorithm) for an online programming challenge site, but I can't seem to push the time down to where it needs to be. The assignment is to, for a number of different 'misspelled' words **w1, w2, ... , wn** and a dictionary **D** compute the editing distances between all words **wi** and all words **di** in the dictionary and, for every **wi**, output the word(s) in the dictionary with the smallest editing distance from **wi**.

At the moment this is how I've implemented my algorithm;

```
main():
  minDistance = 1000 // arbitrary large number
  Let D be the dictionary
  Let W be the set of words that needs ‘correcting’
  For every w in W:
    For every d in D:
      dist = distance(w, d)
      if dist < minDistance:
        minDistance = dist
        Make a linked list minList and add d to it
      if dist == minDistance:
        Add d to minList
    Output minDistance aswell as minList 

distance(w, d):
  Make a matrix M with dimensions (m,n)
  If the last d and this d has any p (start)-letters in common => use M(m, p) from last computation (no need to compute it again) 
  Fill the first row and the first column with their respective ‘index’ //Look at table on Wiki
  For col = 1 to m:
    For row = p to n:
      wagner-fischer(w, d, col, row)

wagner-fischer(w, d, col, row):
  res = M(col-1, row-1) + (1 if w have the same letter at index col-1 as d at row-1)
  addLetter = M(col-1, row) + 1
  deleteLetter = M(col, row-1) + 1
  if addLetter < res:
    res = addLetter
  if deleteLetter < res:
    res = deleteLetter
  return res
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to optimize my implementation further? I'm really struggling at this point and I don't really know how to improve it further. I've done it in Java if that's of any importance.

Comment: I would post this question to Codereview.

Comment: Oh, right! Damn, there's alot of programming subforums on here, hehe. Thanks for the tip!